# Alterar entre branchs no GIT e alterações se manterem no branch atual

Tags: git, github

Bem pessoal eu estava com uma dúvida e ao fazer a pergunta aqui nesse mesmo tópico que estou abrindo eu me auto respondi mas decidi continuar para ajudar alguém que possa ter a mesma dúvida.

Minha dúvida era como fazer alterações em um branch e fazer com que os arquivos modificados ficassem nele sem me "seguirem" caso eu alterasse de branch durante o desenvolvimento, bem é simples basta dar um `git commit` assim as alterações ficarão no branch onde elas estão no momento do `git commit` e portanto ao alterar de branch elas não iram para o novo branch como ocorre caso você não de commit antes de alterar o seu branch.

Bem essa foi a solução que eu achei não sei se é a melhor solução para isso, mas caso vocês conheçam outras opções compartilhem fazendo favor.

**Ajude ao próximo**, na hora de dar `git commit` não esqueça de colocar um comentário `git commit -m "[COMENTÁRIO]"` isso facilita uma interpretação futura tanto pra você quanto para seus colegas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, Mateus. Costumo usar outra alternativa

A forma que você expôs realmente resolve o caso. A alternância de branches é permitida, mas você acaba com um commit a mais no histórico. Eu sou pessoalmente purista quanto a história do código e, quando faço esses commits "sujos", "não prontos" costumo usar um rebase ou cherry-pick depois pra arrumar a casa.

Existe no git um recurso que gosto muito chamado "stash" que serve exatamente para esse cenário: Você fez um commit há alguns minutos e continuou editando. Ai quer alternar de branch e, pra isso, quer seus arquivos de trabalho (working tree) limpos.

O stash compara seus arquivos de trabalho com o último commit que você fez na branch atual (o famoso HEAD), toma as diferenças, guarda numa gaveta e volta o estado para o HEAD, fazendo com que sua working tree fique limpa novamente. Nesse momento a alternância de branches pode seguir. Mais tarde, você pode tomar o que o `git stash` guardou e reaplicar sobre os arquivos. Isso não gera um commit e você pode voltar a trabalhar precisamente do ponto que parou. É como tirar uma coisa do banco do passageiro pra levar alguém de carona de depois voltar a coisa pro banco original quando a pessoa for embora :D .

Seguem alguns exemplos:

`git stash list` - lista os stashs salvos num formato semelhante à

```
stash@{0}: On master: mais conteudo para o arquivo
stash@{1}: On master: primeiro stash!
```

sendo o formato stash@{n}: sua branch : sua mensagem (n é um numero do stash, sendo 0 pro mais recente.

`git stash save "mensagem"`
salva os arquivos versionados não comitados e reseta os arquivos para o último commit

`git stash apply stash@{1}`
aplica o stash 1, retornando as alterações que esse salvou para os arquivos. Pode ser executada em qualquer momento no futuro, não necessáriamente assim que voltar para a branch.

É um recurso muito simples e que me faz falta demais no SVN. Permite que você alterne sem esquentar a cabeça salvando patches por ai.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito bom, também não sou a favor de ficar dando commits assim tão "desnecessários", com toda certeza começarei a trabalhar usando `git stash`. Obrigado.